# K-Means clustering and correlation

Tags: correlation, clustering, k-means, computational-statistics

I ran K-Means on my dataset, it's a small dataset of 200 countries x 6 export sectors. My results formed three clusters.

Now I want to check whether these three clusters are correlated with another feature z, let's say income per capita.

I could do a pearson correlation but I realized that the results are dependent on the magnitude of labels.  So if I had three clusters (0:109, 1:42, 2:25) my correlation coefficient would be entirely different if I relabeled the clusters to (2:109, 1:42, 0:25).

Is there a way for me to perform this correlation that is agnostic to the cluster level 0,1, 2 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to think about this problem. Does it make sense to rephrase your question as: Does the discrete clustering structure explain mean differences in continuous variable z?

If so, the corresponding null hypothesis is: There are no mean differences across clusters in z, or, if you refer to the cluster averages of z as $\mu_{z,1}$, $\mu_{z,2}$, $\ldots$, you then assume $H_0$: $\mu_{z,1}=\mu_{z,2}=\mu_{z,3}=\ldots$.

To test your hypothesis, you may resort to a simple type of ANOVA analysis performing the corresponding omnibus test. If you reject $H_0$, you may run post-hoc t-tests to find the cluster pairs that significantly differ from each other.

Comment: Don't use ANOVA with variance minimization techniques such as k-means. Because they maximized a variant of the test statistic, this is overfitting and the significance scores are nonsense.

Comment: So while I also suggest to use the means and correlate z with mean z, I'd advise to rather not look at the significance of the partitions were formed on data and not hypothetized before looking at the data (but people may disagree here, and argue that z wasn't used for clustering etc.)

Answer (score 0):

K-means cluster labels are not numeric. They are categorical although it is common to use numbers. There is no *order* to them, and you must not use arithmetics on them. So it's better to think of them as A, B, C rather than 1, 2, 3.

Hence, you must not compute correlation with the label.

If you want to check if an independent variable correlates with the clusters, you could (and that would be consistent with the idea of k-means) correlate the original variable with the quantified version:
For every point i, and variable z use qz = mean(z) averaged over the cluster of point i. So if you have three clusters, you get a three-level quantified version qz of z, and you then can look at cor(z,qz).